# Custom control is invisible on winform

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

So I've got three objects "Truck, Employee and Load". I need to be able to visually represent these object by an icon (showing the type of object) and a label (the name of the object).

The way I thought to approach this issue is by creating a custom control. So I did this: **Right-Click Project > Add > User Control > Custom Control**

I then added a picturebox to the designer window. I'll show the code behind below:

```
public partial class DragAbleObject : Control
{

        private Object _value;
        private String _name;

        public DragAbleObject()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.Image = TIS.Client.Properties.Resources._11187316_10206518167692890_1714447113226270672_o;
        }

        public Object Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; }
        }

        public String Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought this should be working, but when I add this control to my form it shows nothing.

Images:
Editor gives errors when embedding them.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl7Oc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJt5M.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWdzW.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to place another controls into yours, derive from `UserControl` instead (add *User Control* instead of *Custom Control*). In most cases that is the appropriate base class of composite controls.

Similarly to a `Form`, you will have a designer where you can place your `PictureBox`.

Comment: I just found out but you beat me to it. Thanks a lot!